# The import android.os.storage.StorageVolume cannot be resolved

Tags: android

Is StorageVolume available as a public API?
I found it's used in a project but I can't find it in a documentation.
Thank you

Comment: there is no storageVolume in storage package in android api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/package-summary.html

Comment: @rajpara That's not quite right. StorageVolume is in that package, but it's not part of the public API. See [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.java#StorageVolume).

Comment: @SteveBlackwell yes that is not in public api, and that is in source, but If the class is not included in public api then it is better not to try to use it, i think so

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think the question sounds like you're trying to set up an android project before reading the documentation. Like @rajpara said, it's best to stick with the public API. Maybe the question would be better if you specify what you're trying to do, what code you're using, and what errors you get.

Comment: I think it is unfair to downvote this question it is reasonable since I am having the absolute same problem at the moment. If you encounter the problem the question is also very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem while trying to update the CMUpdater app in cyanogenmod 10.

In Eclipse, right-click on the project name and choose New -> Folder, name it android-source (or whatever) and click the Advanced button and choose "Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)" and Browse for the directory

/your-drive/android/system/frameworks/base/core/java

(Check that android/os/storage/StorageVolume.java is there first)

Click Finish.

The folder will be added to the list of files and folders on the left.

Right-click on your project and go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source tab

Click Add Folder... and choose the new folder you just made.

Now the import line shouldn't be red anymore. On the other hand, there will be tons of errors in the sources in the folder you just made. You won't be able to build the app from eclipse. On a command line, go to /andriod/system and type

(Only the first time)
. build/envsetup.sh

breakfast your-device-codename

(Every time to build)
mmm path/to/your/app

Also, read this: http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just adding jar files to some Java code, you need to create a full android project. This will be easiest using Eclipse, but even if you're using the command line, you'll need to create a project first before adding code.

See instructions here:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: Thank you Steve. Actually, I am not trying to add the jar to some Java code. I have the full android project that I am trying to get it working.

Comment: Oh, in that case I would say it's best to follow @rajpara's advice and stick to the public API.

Comment: My client works with OEM. They probably need it for a reason. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @Bin if you have to make your application for OEM then i think there is also other resource because OEM's application can access native classes, but it will be better if you search on google according to your requirement or ask very specific & detail question